# Error de violacion de foreign key en PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, postgresql, herencia

Tengo una tabla `Cliente`, una tabla `Cuenta` y una tabla `Titular` de la siguiente forma:

```
CREATE TABLE Cliente(
    DNI varchar(9) NOT NULL,
    nombre varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    apellidos   VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    direccion   VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    edad        int NOT NULL,
    email       varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    telefono    int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Cliente PRIMARY KEY (DNI)
);

CREATE TABLE Cuenta(
    IBAN          varchar(24) NOT NULL,
    numCuenta     varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    saldo         decimal(15,2) default(0.00) check(saldo >= 0) NOT NULL,
    fechaCreacion date NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Cuenta PRIMARY KEY ( IBAN )
);

CREATE TABLE Cuenta_Corriente(
    codOf   int REFERENCES Oficina ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Cuenta_Corriente PRIMARY KEY ( IBAN )
) INHERITS (Cuenta);

CREATE TABLE Titular(
    cliente varchar(9) REFERENCES Cliente ON DELETE CASCADE,
    IBAN    varchar(24) REFERENCES Cuenta ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Titular PRIMARY KEY (cliente,IBAN)
);
```

Quiero realizar los siguientes INSERTS:

```
INSERT INTO Cliente (DNI, nombre, apellidos, direccion, edad, email, telefono) VALUES ('15013567H','Isaac','Lorente Muniesa','Ronda Hornillo 904',77,'galindo@unforgettable.com',666666666);
INSERT INTO Cuenta_Corriente(IBAN, numCuenta, fechaCreacion, codOf) VALUES ('ES7001145541321975169873', 01145541321975169873, '2017-02-18', 7496);
INSERT INTO Titular (Cliente, IBAN) VALUES ('15013567H', 'ES7001145541321975169873');
```

El problema es que al insertar en la tabla Titular me sale el siguiente error: `ERROR:  insert or update on table "titular" violates foreign key constraint "titular_iban_fkey" DETAIL:  Key (iban)=(ES7001145541321975169873) is not present in table "cuenta".` Y no entiendo por qué es si ya existe esa cuenta en la tabla con ese mismo IBAN.

Comment: Si tu haces select de `cuenta`, ves el registro en cuenta_corriente???

Comment: Sí, salen todos los registros a excepción de la columna codOf que solo es visible desde Cuenta_Corriente

Comment: @jachguate no miente pero no leíste completo :) PGSQL tiene herencia en las tablas para 9.x y la documentación no miente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por definición en la [documentación oficial](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-inherit.html#DDL-INHERIT-CAVEATS), no puedes usar *child tables* y foreign keys **al mismo tiempo**.

> A serious limitation of the inheritance feature is that indexes (including unique constraints) and foreign key constraints only apply to single tables, not to their inheritance children. This is true on both the referencing and referenced sides of a foreign key constraint.

Así pues, o usas un constraint trigger que valide cada vez que llamen la tabla padre y evitas usar FK, o creas un trigger function que valide si el ID existe en la tabla hija.

El porqué pasa por problemas para implementar una alternativa eficiente que busque en N tablas hijas para ver si ese valor existe.

Como opinión personal, ese enfoque de OOP para las tablas es horrible (y por eso muere en versiones más recientes de PGSQL) :)

Más ideas en [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24360312/236345)

Comment: Después de probar varias cosas me he dado cuenta de que si primero hago el INSERT en la tabla Cuenta y luego en Cuenta_Corriente funciona pero no tengo ni idea de por qué. Sé que es horrible pero es una práctica de la uni que mezcla un poco sistemas legados y gestores antiguos :)

Comment: Yo estoy manteniendo (sufriendo) un sistema que usa inherits para particionar. La clave es que (por performance, además), no hay FK en esas tablas y toda la responsabilidad de mantener la integridad de esos datos recae en la lógica de negocio. Y pues, tu CHILD TABLE hace poco y nada porque estás duplicando datos para mantener un diseño sólo para que alguien sepa que esas tablas están relacionadas. Denormalizar para que se vea bonito no se ve nada bonito! :P